# What can cause knocking sound when pressing and releasing gas pedal?

Tags: engine, tires, transmission, cv-joint, bushing

I hear a knocking sound whenever I pres the gas pedal and accelerate fast, or when I quickly take my foot off the gas. I hear it at low speeds 25-40mph. Just replaced the CV axles, put on new tires, and did the alignment. What can cause this sound cuz I took it to the mechanic and all mechanical parts looks good??

Comment: Maybe a bad engine or transmission mount

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you describe things better? What kind of knocking sound? Does it sound/feel like it's coming from the suspension? Is it rhythic or does it just go thunk once on each acceleration or deceleration? If rhythmic, does it change pitch with engine speed or with vehicle speed? Give us something to go on?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a worn mount, suspension, or steering problem. They create a knocking noise when taking the foot off the accelerator pedal.